# Python: AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'format'

Tags: python, python-2.7

i am trying out the code below and the attribute error popped up. I am new to Python and would appreciate to know what I can do to correct this error.

```
    with open(csv_file_path,'wb+') as fout:
            csv_file = csv.writer(fout)
            csv_file.writerow(list(column_names))
            with open(json_file_path) as fin:
                for line in fin:
                    line_contents = json.loads(line)
                    csv_file.writerow(get_row(line_contents,column_names))

    read_and_write_file(json_file,csv_file,column_names)

    if isinstance(line_value,unicode):
                row.append({0}.format(line_value.encode('utf-8')))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Json_convert.py", line 89, in <module>
    read_and_write_file(json_file, csv_file, column_names)
  File "Json_convert.py", line 19, in read_and_write_file
    csv_file.writerow(get_row(line_contents,column_names))
  File "Json_convert.py", line 62, in get_row
    row.append({0}.format(line_value.encode('utf-8')))
AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'format'
```

Comment: It should be `row.append("{0}".format(line_value.encode('utf-8')))`

Comment: you don't need format for a single item like this...`row.append(line_value.encode('utf-8')))`

Comment: thank you. i think it works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python, using curly brackets as you did (where you wrote `{0}`) is for creating an inbuilt object known as a set. A set is (like in mathematics) an un-ordered collection of unique elements, and is cannot be formatted, and hence there is no `set.format` method, leading to the attribute error when you tried to call the format method on a set: `{0}.format(..)`.

You may have meant:

`row.append("{0}".format(line_value.encode('utf-8')))`

This creates a string, which does have a format method, so this should work.

Answer (score -1):

use type caste, replace your this line,

```
row.append({0}.format(line_value.encode('utf-8')))
```

with

```
row.append({0}.format(str(line_value).encode('utf-8')))
```

and now you can format it to 'utf-8'

Comment: thank you, i tried the solution above with the missing parentheses and that seemed to work